# SP 2013 : Error Cannot open database "Search_Service_Application_1_DB_2fxx requested by the login. Login failed for user 'xxx'

Tags: search, enterprise-search

When i click on Content Sources on my Central Administration in SharePoint 2013. I get the below error

> Cannot open database "Search_Service_Application_1_DB_2fxxxxx"
>   requested by the login. The login failed.  Login failed for user
>   'xxx'.

When I went to database server and when i click on + sign of respective database it was not opening. Why is this happening ?? My Search on site works fine but not able to open most of the search administration pages on central Administration.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the Admin Database for the SSA is damaged if SQL cannot open it. I would restore it from a backup or recreate it.

I cover these provisioning options in my Search course on Pluralsight: http://bit.ly/abSearch and provide sample scripts.

Comment: Can you send me the steps how to recreate it.

Comment: The answer to that depends on your farm architecture. There is no one "right" answer. You need to review the search components for your farm and decide where each component should be run based on your business requirements. If you just need to recreate the search application you can use the Configuration Wizard, though I'd never do that in production.

Comment: You meant Configuration Wizard means when you navigate to http://abc.org/_admin/ServiceApplications.aspx and click on new and choose search service application a new iframe window opens up. is that what u meant ??

Comment: No, though that is an option. I meant the Farm Configuration Wizard. I don't use it in production. I use PowerShell in production environments.

Comment: What is the difference between Farm Configuration Wizard and PowerShell?? I guess farm configuration wizards uses the same commands and done the work. Anyway if we have to use only powershell in prod then do u have any commandlts which i can run to recreate Admin Database for the SSA

Comment: HUGE difference. The FCW provides no control for what servers are configured for the services, limited database naming and only single instance provisioning. PowerShell provides the most flexibility and control and is needed in a multiserver configuration. Answer updated.